# Как изменить значение глобальной переменной, используя addEventlistener?

Tags: javascript

```js
function redirect_c() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cal_calc = 0;   
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function maaam ( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;

     for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( 'your-age' == inputs[i].name ) {
            var age = inputs[i].value ;
        }
        if ( 'your-sex' == inputs[i].name ) {
            var sex = inputs[i].value ;
        }
        if ( 'your-height' == inputs[i].name ) {
            var height = inputs[i].value ;
        }
        if ( 'your-weight' == inputs[i].name ) {
            var weight = inputs[i].value ;
        }
        if ( 'your-waist' == inputs[i].name ) {
            var waist = inputs[i].value ;
        }

    }
    if ('Мужской' == sex ) { 
        cal_calc = ((9.99 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (4.92 * age) + 5) * 1.35 ;
     } 
    else if ('Женский' == sex ) {
        cal_calc = ((9.99 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (4.92 * age) - 161) * 1.35 ; 
    }
    if ('20' == age && '100' == weight && 'Мужской' == sex ){
    location = 'страница'
    }
    /
}, false );
    document.getElementById("cal_calc").innerHTML = cal_calc;


</script>
<?php
}
```

`document.getElementById("cal_calc").innerHTML = cal_calc;` выводит `0`.

Как заставить его выводить результат вычислений?

Comment: Ну так у Вас данная строчка лежит за результатами вычислений, вне обработчика события `wpcf7submit` поэтому 0 и выводит. Переместите его в данный слушатель и будет выводиться данные после отправки формы.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Тогда код обрывается на этой строчке и обработчик событий перестает работать полностью

Comment: Что значит код обрывается? и перестаёт работать полностью?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Ну например если вставить перед "location = 'страница' ", то не будет выполняться переход на нужную страницу и т.д.

Comment: и? после вставки его в данный обработчик, я нажимаю на отправку формы и далее у меня что-то высчитывается и подставляется туда куда нужно я не пойму что у Вас перестает работать и как это определяется. Единственное что меня смущает что это всё в php коде выводится. А что у Вас падает очень трудно понять по данному коду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ...
 if ('Мужской' == sex ) { 
    cal_calc = ((9.99 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (4.92 * age) + 5) * 1.35 ;
 } else if ('Женский' == sex ) {
    cal_calc = ((9.99 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (4.92 * age) - 161) * 1.35 ; 
 }
 if (document.getElementById("cal_calc"))
   document.getElementById("cal_calc").innerHTML = cal_calc;
 else
   console.log("Element with id=cal_calc does not exist.");
 ...
```

---

> Не работает, в HTML не находит Id "cal_calc"

Как это - не работает? Как раз прекрасно работает. Разбирайтесь, почему элемента с этим `id` нет на странице.

---

Вам следовало указать, что речь идет об `id="cal_calc"` на второй странице. Оно так не работает. Вы не можете из первой страницы изменить дерево второй. Вы можете передать на вторую страницу дополнительные параметры в "query string" url-а, а на второй странице что-то сделать в зависимости от наличия/значения этих параметров.

```
location = 'страница' + '?cal_calc=' + cal_calc;
```

```js
var cal_calc = "no param in query string"
// var queryString = window.location.search;
var queryString = "cal_calc=123.456&aaa=bbb";
console.log("queryString =", queryString);
var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
if (params.get("cal_calc")) {
  cal_calc = params.get("cal_calc")
  console.log("has cal_calc =", cal_calc);
} else {
  console.log("does not have cal_calc");
}
var div = document.getElementById("cal_calc") || document.createElement("div");
div.textContent = cal_calc;
if (!div.parentNode) {
  console.log("adding new element");
  div.id = "cal_calc";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
} else {
  console.log("element was in the page");
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99888/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------).

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    var queryString = window.location.search;
var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
if (params.get("cal_calc")) {
  var div = document.getElementById("cal_calc") || document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = params.get("cal_calc");
  if (!div.parentNode) {
    div.id = "cal_calc";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<p id="cal_calc"></p>
```

вставил весь этот код в виджет "HTML-код" в elementor, все равно не выводит число там, @igor выручайте )